# How to output a Json Array and loop through variables

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a small ticket app on my site where users can buy tickets and add guests.
I'm sending out the Receipt Email and need to display the guest names.

Note, There can be up to 7 guests.

The Guest are in an array. How can I display the guests properly in the email?

Here is what I'm working with.

**Email:**

```
@php
$array = json_encode($guests);
@endphp

@component('mail::message')
# Greetings,...

## Here is an outline of your transaction:
@component('mail::panel')
...
- Guests: @if(!empty($array)  && isset($array)  && is_array($array))
@foreach ($array as $item)
{{ $item->guest_name  }} | {{ $item->gluten  }}
@endforeach
@endif
@endcomponent
```

The array at the top, wrapped in the PHP Tags outputs the following data:

`[{"no":1,"guest_name":"John Doe","gluten_free":"Yes"}]`

I'm currently not getting any errors to debug, but I'm not getting anything outputted in the email either.

I'm using Laravel so here is my Mail File:
I tried writting the logic in here as well, but same results.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use ...

class NewOrder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public ...
    public $guests;

    public function __construct(
            $...
            $guests
    )
    {
            $...
            $this->guests = $guests;
            // $this->guests = json_encode($guests);
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Order Email')->markdown('emails.user.newOrderEmail');
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do json_encode the variable it would become a string. You should be able to directly loop over `$guests` array (assuming it is already an array or a collection, not any other type).
Probably you aren't getting any output as `@if(!empty($array)  && isset($array)  && is_array($array))` condition is false, as `$array` is a string, not an array.

You could rewrite your code as:

```php
@component('mail::message')
# Greetings,...

## Here is an outline of your transaction:
@component('mail::panel')
...
- Guests:
@unless(empty($guests))
@foreach ($guests as $guest)
{{ $guest['guest_name']  }} | {{ $guest['gluten_free'] }}
@endforeach
@endunless

@endcomponent
```

Comment: When I try this approach I get the error ... `Trying to get property 'guest_name' of non-object` .... If I output the array I get the following: `[{"no":5,"guest_name":"John Doe","gluten_free":"Yes"}]`  Do you know why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Can you post the output of dd($guests) in your NewOrder class's constructor?

Comment: `array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "no" => 7
    "guest_name" => "John Doe"
    "gluten_free" => "No"
  ]
]`

Comment: If I add multiple guests I get:

`array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "no" => 1
    "guest_name" => "John Doe"
    "gluten_free" => "No"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "no" => 2
    "guest_name" => "Jane Doe"
    "gluten_free" => "Yes"
  ]
]`

Comment: Seems like each element of the $guests array is an array as well, not an object. I updated my answer to fix the problem

Comment: That worked perfect. I really appreciate the help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to push all the elements into one master array and then need to pass it mail function.

```
$details = array();
- Guests: @if(!empty($array)  && isset($array)  && is_array($array))
@foreach ($array as $item)
//{{ $item->guest_name  }} | {{ $item->gluten  }}
 $current_user = array('name'=>$item->guest_name,'gluten'=>$item->gluten);
 array_push($details,$current_user);
@endforeach
```

Now pass the `$details` array to mail, I dont know how you do it, but this is how you can pass multiple values store it in array and pass that array.

Answer (score 0):

**Mail**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use ...

class NewOrder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public ...
    public $guests;

    public function __construct(
            $...
            $guests
    )
    {
            $...
            $this->guests = $guests;
            // $this->guests = json_encode($guests);
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Order Email')
            ->markdown('emails.user.newOrderEmail')
            ->with([
                'ticket_id' => $this->guests['ticket_id'],
                ....
            ]);
    }
}
```

**Markdown**

```
{{$ticket_id}}
```

Comment: So if I do `$array = json_encode($guests);` and then output `{{ $array }}` in my markdown email blade........ I get the following results....... `[{"no":5,"guest_name":"John Doe","gluten_free":"Yes"}]`  ........... I do as you suggested `->with([
                'guest_name' => $this->guest_name,
                'gluten_free' => $this->gluten_free,`........... and get error `Undefined property: App\Mail\NewOrder::$guest_name`................ In Markdown I add {{$guest_name}} {{$gluten_free}}.....What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry i forgot i edited my code so you can do this its not `'glueten_free' => $this->guests['gluten_free']